# Suddenly unable to save ArcGIS Online WebApp?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm putting together a quick webapp for a client using ArcGIS Online's webapp builder. However, it all of a sudden will not allow me to save any of my changes to the webapp. The save button and all of the options in the expandable menu are grayed out. As far as I know, it is like this even nobody has it open (although I believe this shouldn't be a problem anyway).

I have been unable to find an answer through ESRI's site. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you currently have enough Credits on the account?

Comment: Which web app are you trying to use?

Comment: @whyzar I am not sure what you are referring to with credits.

I am using the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS, not any of the preset ones.

Additionally, I am able to save changes on all of my other webapps, but not this one.

Comment: I have the same problem this week (Oct 2016)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/97718)

Comment: Had the same problem. I resized the web app builder window and the save button began to work

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a problem I was having with ArcGIS Online web app and found this on the Esri site.  Perhaps it can help you:

The link for this is

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000013067

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't think anyone else has this app opened in another location but you need to be sure. If anyone else has access to it contact them and confirm. I had a similar issue where i was unable to save changes because another user left it open while they were away.